# Get attribute from Soap Response Header in PHP

Tags: php, soap, service, web, header

I am using PHP to connect to a [Web Service](http://www.webcrm.com/apiTechDocumentation/).

I need to connect to the web service with some login details so I can generate a Ticket to start using the methods available.

Here is some code:

```
//Connect To WebCrm API
$client = new SoapClient("http://b2b-email.net/apicrm1/webCRMAPI.asmx?wsdl",    array('trace' => 1));

//Login
$ticket = $client->Authenticate(array('code' => 'rhgkhgk','user' =>'myusername','password' =>'apass'));
```

From this in the response soap header a ticket will be generated. This is generated under Ticket Header Then GUID. (See Below)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Header>
         <TicketHeader xmlns="http://www.webcrm.com/">
             <Guid>TICKET->>>>>>>>e446373e-8fg0-4dfc-b876-41f3bc8990dd</Guid>
        </TicketHeader>
      </soap:Header>
       <soap:Body>
        <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://www.webcrm.com/">
          <AuthenticateResult>
        <Message />
        <Code>0</Code>
      </AuthenticateResult>
    </AuthenticateResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need this ticket ID to perform any other tasks using the web service but how can access it and use it within my code?

I have tried using below:

```
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();
```

However this outputs like below:

```
6d5933d3-46ff-4690-893d-2af04806668c->>>>>>>>0<<<<<ZERO ON THE END
```

A zero is always on the end when it shouldn't be?

Any help on why this is happening on the best way i can achieve accessing the ticket from Soap Header is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php):

```
$soapclient->__soapCall("soapmethod", array(parameters), null, $input_headers, &$output_headers);
```

$output_headers should then contain the headers from the response message.

`$client->__getLastResponse()` returns the XML of the last response. You are viewing this in your browser, and your browser is trying to interpret this as HTML. Because of this, it will not show any XML tags and only show text. That is why the 0 is displayed. You can view the whole XML in several ways:

- View the source of the PHP page
- Wrap the `echo` statement in `<xmp></xmp>` tags.
- Call [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) on the XML before echoing it.

Comment: Ok I did try this soap call however i just get this error **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in** This is caused by the line `$client->__soapCall("Authenticate", array("gddfffdg","dfgdfgd","dggfdf"), null, $input_headers, &$output_headers);`